# For datadog how to check posgresql up and running (on Linuxredhat server)

Tags: postgresql, datadog

We are not willing to use DD agent. How can we know if PostgresSQL is up and running on my Redhat linux server so that I can create an alert when postgres is down.

Comment: "We are not willing to use DD agent." Could you elaborate on why, so folks don't suggest similarly problematic solutions? Have you considered something like Nagios, Monit, etc.?

Comment: we have limited licenses of DD agent

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor a database from a different host as long as the host the agent is running on has access. So for this section in the config file:

```
instances:
  - host: localhost
    port: 5432
```

https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/master/postgres/datadog_checks/postgres/data/conf.yaml.example#L4

instead of using `localhost` you can set the IP. This will allow you to monitor your database without adding a new agent. Then you would just follow the normal [postrgres setup](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/postgres/#prepare-postgres) and you will have access to all the metrics and [service checks](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/postgres/#service-checks) including `postgres.can_connect` which is probably what you care about.